# Search Bar inside ViewCell doesn't allow input from keyboard in Android

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and I wanted to put some controls inside a TableView. One of them is a SearchBar, which is inside a ViewCell.

I tested this one in my Android phone and it doesn't allow me to input from keyboard, I tap on it and it doesn't bring keyboard.

Perhaps is bug or I am using the wrong Cell type for a SearchBar.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
...
    <TableView>
          <TableRoot>
          <TableSection Title="Cliente">
              <ViewCell>
                  <SearchBar x:Name="txtBusquedaCliente" Placeholder="Seleccione..." />
              </ViewCell>
              <SwitchCell x:Name="swFormato" Text="Shor Format: " ></SwitchCell>
          </TableSection>  
        ...
    </TableView>
...
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bug that's been sitting in Xamarin's queue for almost a year: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4882
Would love to hear work arounds if you found any... since you made the post.